# Do matrix product to outputs of two models in keras

Tags: python, machine-learning, computer-vision, deep-learning, keras

I am developing a classification model by using CNN, and now I want to apply a classification algorithm in my problem([Bilinear CNN Models for Fine-grained Visual Recognition Tsung-Yu Lin Aruni RoyChowdhury Subhransu Maji
University of Massachusetts, Amherst](http://vis-www.cs.umass.edu/bcnn/docs/bcnn_iccv15.pdf)).

Concretely, now I want to do outer-product to two output matrix of two CNN model, and I have finished the transpose of matrix, now I ONLY want to multiply two matrix in **keras**, whose sizes is (None, 512, 49) and (None, 49, 512).

I try to use **Merge** layer in keras, but some errors appeared:

When I use **dot** mode,

> ValueError: Dimension incompatibility using dot mode: 49 != 512. Layer
>   shapes: (None, 512, 49), (None, 49, 512)

When I use **multiply** mode,

> ValueError: Only layers of same output shape can be merged using mul
>   mode. Layer shapes: [(None, 512, 49), (None, 49, 512)]

I don't know how to solve it, please help me! Here are some code of my problem:

```
t_model = applications.VGG16(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, 
                                input_shape=(224, 224, 3))
model_a = Sequential()
model_a.add(t_model)
def trans_1(conv):
    conv = tf.reshape(conv, [-1, 49, 512])
    return conv
model_a.add(Lambda(trans_1, output_shape=[49, 512]))

s_model = applications.VGG16(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, 
                                input_shape=(224, 224, 3))
model_b = Sequential()
model_b.add(s_model)
def trans_2(conv):
    conv = tf.reshape(conv, [-1, 49, 512])
    conv = tf.transpose(conv, perm = [0, 2, 1])
    return conv
model_b.add(Lambda(trans_2, output_shape=[512, 49]))

f_model = Sequential()
f_model.add(Merge([model_b, model_a], mode='dot'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, don't use `Sequential()` when your model isn't sequential. Use the [functional API](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/) instead.

Also,

- Since the two VGG16 models share the same input image, you can use the `input_tensor` argument to provide the shared input.
- Note that VGG16 has fixed layer names. You have to change the layer names for one of the models to prevent the "All layer names should be unique." error.
- Keras has a built-in `Reshape` layer, there's no need to use TF here.
- Use `Dot` instead of the deprecated `Merge` layer.

Back to your question, the `axes` argument in `Dot` specifies which axes will be reduced. So you don't need to transpose the tensor before applying it.

```
input_tensor = Input(shape=(224, 224, 3))
t_model = applications.VGG16(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_tensor=input_tensor)
t_output = Reshape((49, 512))(t_model.output)
s_model = applications.VGG16(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_tensor=input_tensor)
for layer in s_model.layers:
    layer.name += '_1'
s_output = Reshape((49, 512))(s_model.output)
merged = Dot(axes=1)([s_output, t_output])
```